# Is it possible for a non US resident to have a bank account in the US?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, non-resident

Even though I am not an US citizen and I don't live in the US, I was able (a few years ago) to open a bank account in Wells Fargo without having any proof of US residency.
They recently started requiring such proof, which I can't provide.

My question: is it still possible to have an account in the US? I know there are solutions like Wise, but I would prefer real, traditional banks.

Do you know if it's still possible to have such account? Any practical experience?

Comment: Valid question. But every bank will have their own rules, and they might change anytime. This site is not supporting managing such lists, especially ever-changing ones.

Comment: If you aren't a US citizen, and you don't live in the US, why do you need a US account?

Comment: For traveling, freelancing, online purchasing etc

Comment: Also saving in a different (better) currency.

Comment: @Aganju it's a good thing that the tax code never changes.

Comment: @Aganju I disagree with closing this question. Building on Franck Dernoncourt 's point, if we think we can answer tax questions despite the tax rules changing all the time, then we ought to be able to answer questions about residency proof rules in general. The question does not ask for a complete and current list, just "still possible" and "practical experience".

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt to be fair to him, the original question did ask "in which banks (...)". I have then edited it and requested to be opened.

Comment: I'm not the one that closed the question, it's a voting of multiple people. And I'm also not the one making the rules. Finally, there is a vote you can make to re-open the question.